# How to sort product by position, if every product has same position?

Tags: magento2, sorting, product-sorting, sort-by-position

I read somewhere that if all product has same position it will sort by product id, but I don't think its sorting by Id.

Here are a few screenshots I am sharing which I am sorting by position problem is that every time I click on `position` it will show any new type of sorting.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

also, I created a product carousel for the same category collection, with `position` sorting and showing the first product which I don't know why it's come first.

Here is my code for collection:

```
public function setSlider() 
{
     $getCategory = $this->_scopeConfig->getValue('Carousel_Section/Carousel_'.$id.'/Carousel_Six_field', \Magento\Store\Model\ScopeInterface::SCOPE_STORE);
     $category = $this->factory->create()->load($getCategory);
     $ProductFilterCollection = $category->getProductCollection()->addAttributeToSelect('price',true)->setFlag('has_stock_status_filter', true)->setPageSize($getLimit)->addAttributeToSelect('*')->setOrder('position', 'asc');
}
```

Everything is working fine, just curious about how `position` sorting works if every product has the same `position`?

Comment: ref link => https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/121215/magento-2-get-custom-collection-by-asc-sort-order-with-position-0-at-end-of-lis

Comment: @SavanPatel I check that already, I don't think its my answer

Comment: @SagarParikhSGR have you get any solution for this issue? I am getting same issue after migration Magento 2.3

Comment: @VinodKumar No, share the link if you found the answer

Comment: No, I didn't get right now.